# Json Values on Screen Objective c

Tags: iphone, json, cocoa-touch

```
NSDictionary *allDatDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *responseData = [allDatDictionary objectForKey:@"responseData"];
NSDictionary *arrayOfResult = [responseData objectForKey:@"results"];

for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfResult) {
    NSString *title = [diction objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *content = [diction objectForKey:@"content"];
    NSString *url = [diction objectForKey:@"url"];


    [array addObject:title];
    [content1 addObject:content];
    [url1 addObject:url];

   NSLog(@"title: %@, \n Content: %@ \n, Url: %@ \n",  [diction objectForKey:@"title"], [diction objectForKey:@"content"],[diction objectForKey:@"url"]);

    NSString *text = @"";

    text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@%@\nURL: %@\nContent: %@\n\n", text, [diction objectForKey:@"title"],[diction objectForKey:@"url"],[diction objectForKey:@"content"]];
```

Hey guys, I got the json and I need to show title, content and url on screen. I don't need table ranting like this just show on screen. NSLog shows everything but when I try to write on a `UILabel` it just shows 1 result. Any tips how I can do that? thanks

Comment: To show more than one set of results you've got to have more than one set of labels.  That's why they make tables.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `labelTitle`'s text in a for loop, so you're only going to see the last result, because you keep changing it each time thru the loop. If you want to see all of the results, you'll have to build up a string that contains all of them and then set that as the text of the label.

At the top of the `for` loop, declare an `NSString` variable and set it to `@""`, like the following:

```
NSString *text = @"";
```

Then each time thru the loop, instead of setting the label text to your string, build up this string that you're saving at the top, like the following:

```
text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@\n", text, [diction objectForKey:@"title"]];
```

You can see how I modified that format string. It takes the previous text you've saved, adds to it your new title, and then adds a carriage return.

As an alternative, you could have an `NSMutableArray` at the top, and add your strings to that array each time you go thru the `for` loop. Then at the end, you can use the `NSArray` method `componentsJoinedByString:`, using a carriage return as the separator, to get an `NSString` containing all of the individual strings that you added to the array.

After you have this one string, using either of these methods, you can set that as the text on the label.

Comment: Im a beginner on object c , can u explain how i can do that? thx

Comment: I added more details to my answer. Take a look at it.

Comment: thx for replay its more easy the way u said, i try to find something about [componentsJoinedByString:] and its not so easy and i don't know how i can  show all results